# How can I route to a child route based on the resolved route data?

Tags: angular, redirect, routes, angular-resolver

I'm loading a module with data from the resolver.
The loaded module has the usual empty-path redirect to the first child route. But I want to redirect to a specific route based on the resolved data.

In the current example I have a child module with three components. 
The Resolver in the root module provides the data to which component should be redirected to.

AppModule:

```js
const routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'steps',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },  {
    path: 'steps',
    loadChildren: './steps/steps.module#StepsModule',
    resolve: {
      step: StepResolver,
    }
  },
]

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

ChildModule:

```js
const routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'step1', // <-- this has to be dynamic based on the provided data
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },  {
    path: 'step1',
    component: Step1Component
  },  {
    path: 'step2',
    component: Step2Component
  }, {
    path: 'step3',
    component: Step3Component
  },
]

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ CommonModule, RouterModule.forChild(routes) ],
  declarations: [ Step1Component, Step2Component, Step3Component ],
})
export class StepsModule { }
```

The Resolver returns the step that should be redirected to

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class StepResolver implements Resolve<string> {
  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<string> {
    return of('step2');
  }
}
```

How can I redirect to the route based on the provided data?
Are there any routing hooks that I can use?

Throughts:

- CanActivate on the empty child path -> CanActivate is called after provide, so: no data
- load an empty component in empty child path and trigger the redirect at OnInit -> a bit smelly for me

Comment: So your resolver either returns `step1`, `step2` or `step3`? How does it determine what step to return?

Comment: Its only a stub. In my real app I load data from a server and determine the step from that.

Comment: There will always be a string containing the next step? It would be helpful if you could provide the actual code for the resolver.

Comment: The business logic for mapping the resolved data to the redirect route is not the issue. The Question is, where I have to place the commands for the routing. And this place should have access to the provided data.

Answer (score 0):

You could evaluate what next step is necessary and then navigate to the the specific route:

```
this.route.navigate([yourStep]);
```

You would have to import `Router`:

```
constructor(private route: Router) { }
```

**Edit:**
Create a service with something like this:

```
goToStep(step: string) {
  this.route.navigate([step]);
}
```

And the resolver considering the code you provided:

```
resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<string> {
   return this.stepService.goToStep('step2');
}
```

Comment: to the Edit: Hm, could work but is imho not a good solution. Regarding the SRP the only task of a provider is to provide data.
A guard would be the best way, because by design it can return an UrlTree - but the resolcver is the lase called routing Hook.

Perhaps I write a service, subscribe the RoutingEnd and redirect then.